# Apache Flink Windowing At Specific Start and End Times

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have a use case where I would like to compute windows with pre-determined start times and end times. For example, I want to compute all events within April 1st at 1pm to April 7th at 1pm.

I figured I can compute daily windows and keep the results in state, but this seems optimal.

Does Flink support time windowing at pre-determined start and end times?

Comment: I guess it isn't generally possible with windows, You probably need to fall back to manual grouping of events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you could implement this as either a batch job or as a bounded streaming job, and simply aggregate all of the data together, not with a window, but with reduce or something similar.

Comment: This makes sense, thanks for the response!